# Magento 2: How to increase link expire time for Reset Password

Tags: magento2, customer, password, link

I have 5K Customers. Previouly link expire time is set to 2 hours. I already send email to all customers for "Reset Password".

Now i want to change their Link Expire Time. I think only way to do via DB Table Change.

Table 'customer_entity', Fields `rp_token` & `rp_token_created_at` fields

How to achieve this?

Comment: you can change it from admin system configuration customer configuration section.

Comment: U didn't get my question correctly. It will change Customers Link Expire who already requested before changing this limit?

Comment: Ohh, You have just sent all mail and after you want to process something for expire link, Right?

Comment: Yes. Now you got @Rakesh

Comment: have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: No @Rakesh Still looking

Answer (score 4):

Set Expiration time from backend,

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Password Options
>   -> Recovery Link Expiration Period (hours)

You can change 2 to any value in hour.
For oneday period limit you can set it as 24 in above field.

Comment: hope it cannot be reduced below 1 i.e 30 min and so on

Comment: While this answer doesn't resolve the specific issue here (it won't apply to emails that have already been sent out). It's worth pointing that this is the usual way to increase the link expire time.

Comment: With the latest version of Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.5-p1 path has been changed to `Stores -> Configuation -> Advanced -> Admin -> Security -> Recovery Link Expiration Period (hours)`